# Redmine referencing keywords in case of merge

Tags: svn, redmine

We are using Redmine with SVN for issue and bug tracking.

We use referencing keywords to automatically change the tickets status in case of commit
but I would like to know if it is possible to ignore these referencing keywords in merge message ?

Concrete example of my problem:

I fix a bug, my svn commit message contains "fixes #XXX"
So my Redmine ticket XXX has been changed to "To be tested" status (because of the keywords "fixes")

Then, the tester validates the correction and changes the status to "Resolved".

After that, if someone merge my revisions, I realised that Redmine changes again the status to "To be tested".

The reason is that the merge message contains all commits messages and in particular my "fixes #XXX". 
So Redmine reuse the referencing keywords.

Is there a solution ?

Thank you for your help

Comment: I'm not aware of such feature, however Redmine is open-source, and you are welcome to contribute and submit patch to Redmine.org or request a feature, and somebody else might do it for you... What you are requesting is a keyword on repository commit messages which will cause that after it, all actions are ignored, except referencing commit messages to issue.  Very good feature I would use it also!

Comment: I've done it for you http://www.redmine.org/issues/30014

Comment: @Aleksandar Thank you !

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The proper solution is to configure your tracker's workflow so that you can't change from "Resolved" to "To be tested".  You probably want to do that anyways.